# How to append global list variable in try/except exception in Python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to append global list variable with new words in try/except exceptions, but after try/except I get empty list.

```
    list = []                              # created empty list with global scope
    def try_multiple_operations(j):
            try:
                jopen = urllib2.urlopen(j) # opened url for parsing content
                versions = jopen.read()    # read and save to variable
                version = pq(versions)     # filtering content with pyquery
                ....                       # pyquery operations
                list.append(version)
            except urllib2.URLError:       # urllib2 exception
                list.append('0.0')
            except urllib2.HTTPError:      # urllib2 exception
                list.append('0.0')
executor = concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(5)
futures = [executor.submit(try_multiple_operations, j) for j in list]
concurrent.futures.wait(futures)
print len(list)                        # 0 elements
```

At the end I got empty list. How can I add/append new results to global list within try/except?

Comment: Did you run the function?

Comment: try running the function.

Comment: Sorry, I updated code. I've tried already but no changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several problems. First, `list` (which really should be renamed so that you don't shadow the built-in `list` function) is empty, so

```
futures = [executor.submit(try_multiple_operations, j) for j in list]
```

runs your function zero times.

The second is that a `ProcessPoolExecutor` runs the worker in another process. The worker would update that process's `list` global, not the one in the main process. You should use one of the other pool methods such as `map` and have your worker return its result.

Since your code isn't runnable, I cooked up a different working example

```
import concurrent.futures

def try_multiple_operations(j):
    try:
        if j % 2:
            raise ValueError('oops')
        return '%d even' % j
    except ValueError:
        return '%d odd' % j

executor = concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(5)
my_list = list(executor.map(try_multiple_operations, range(10)))
print(my_list)
```

And your code could be changed to

```
def try_multiple_operations(j):
        try:
            jopen = urllib2.urlopen(j) # opened url for parsing content
            versions = jopen.read()    # read and save to variable
            version = pq(versions)     # filtering content with pyquery
            ....                       # pyquery operations
            return version
        except urllib2.URLError:       # urllib2 exception
            return '0.0'
        except urllib2.HTTPError:      # urllib2 exception
            return '0.0'

url_list = [   ...something... ]
executor = concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(5)
my_list = list(executor.map(try_multiple_operations, url_list)
print len(my_list)                        # 0 elements
```